# Stop Eclipse from formatting JSP files

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-wtp

Eclipse keeps messing up java code inside my JSP files. How can I disable formatting of JSP files on accidental formatting?

[image: sample]

Comment: Deactivate or use another shortcut for formatting. Or use format off tags in these files.

Comment: Is there a way to tell WTP to not to format JSP files only?

Comment: No, there is not. I am unclear on what is being messed up, though--your Java formatting preferences are meant to be in effect as it is the Java formatting that is being invoked.

Comment: I am using the **Java Conventions [built in]** profile.

Comment: What's the message it's reporting on line 79 in the image? Do you have unresolved Java syntax errors that could be affecting its formatting?

Comment: I dont think so. This code is from an existing system and it works fine.

Comment: And the message on that line, when you hover over the line number?

Comment: Can you then explain more clearly in what way it's messed up?